# Codificação de arquivo em ASC II

Tags: php, arquivo, codificação-de-caracteres, sistema-de-arquivos

Pessoal estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em php que gera arquivos de remessa para o banco e esses arquivos tem que ser com as especificações abaixo:

> Sistema de Codificação - Plataforma Baixa
>
> ASC II - inclusive o arquivo deverá conter delimitadores de registro no final de cada registro,
> (ODOA), bem como finalizador de arquivo, no final do trailler, (1A).

Esse trecho é do manual do bradesco, e eu não sei se entendi muito bem. Pelo que eu pude entender os arquivos de remessa tem que estar codificados em ASC II e como faço isso? Procurei no manual do php e encontrei uma função que pode codificar strings para ASC II, ela se chama "mb_convert_encoding()" seria esse o caminho?

E esses delimitadores de final de registro(linha) seriam as quebras de linha?

O finalizador de arquivo (1A) que o manual cita seria o que a função fclose() coloca no final do arquivo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os caracteres deverão conter códigos **ASCII** padrão de 7-bits (de 0 até 127, ou seja, nada de **UNICODE** ou outra codificação de acentos ou símbolos), ao término de cada registro/linha um você incluirá os caracteres 13 e 10 (quando você for montar a *string* para escrever no arquivo coloque um `."\r\n";` ao término do arquivo, antes do `fclose()`, envie um `chr(0x1a);`. Eu te recomendo usar a função `fwrite()` e trabalhar com o arquivo em formato binário ("wb").

Comment: eu vou te fazer a mesma pergunta que fiz para o Bacco. Esses caracteres não são automaticamente colocados pela constante PHP_EOL e a função fclose() respectivamente?

Comment: Isto é um arquivo de textos padrão de DOS, com as quebras de linhas feitas com CR (0x0d) e LF (0x0a) e o EOF (0x1a, ou CTRL+Z) marcando o término dele.

Comment: A PHP_EOL é uma definição interna do PHP com relação ao mecanismo de quebra de linha no sistema em que ele está sendo executado (CR+LF no Windows, LF em Unix etc). Ainda recomendo que você grave este arquivo em formato binário para evitar surpresas inesperadas.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo fazendo do jeito que você disse. Só o chr(0x1a) que não precisava, o manual do banco está errado, o pessoal da central me ajudou.

Comment: No DOS você podia criar um arquivo texto direto na linha de comando fazendo `copy con arquivo.txt`, daí você digitava o texto e finalizava pressionando, veja só, «Ctrl»+«Z»... :-)

Answer (score 4):

A grafia é "ASCII". Abreviação de "American Standard Code for Information Interchange", que é "Código Padrão Americano para o Intercâmbio de Informação".

Em princípio, não há o que converter. Os encodings mais comuns, seja ISO-8859-1, WIN-1252, ou mesmo UTF-8, usam a tabela ASCII como base.

ASCII são os caracteres de 0 a 127, conforme a tabela a seguir:

```
Caracteres "imprimíveis"
=======================================
Dec    Hex   Bin         Caractere
------ ----- ----------- --------------
 32    20    00100000    Espaço
 33    21    00100001    ! 
 34    22    00100010    " 
 35    23    00100011    # 
 36    24    00100100    $ 
 37    25    00100101    % 
 38    26    00100110    & 
 39    27    00100111    ' 
 40    28    00101000    ( 
 41    29    00101001    ) 
 42    2A    00101010    * 
 43    2B    00101011    + 
 44    2C    00101100    , 
 45    2D    00101101    - 
 46    2E    00101110    . 
 47    2F    00101111    / 
 48    30    00110000    0 
 49    31    00110001    1 
 50    32    00110010    2 
 51    33    00110011    3 
 52    34    00110100    4 
 53    35    00110101    5 
 54    36    00110110    6 
 55    37    00110111    7 
 56    38    00111000    8 
 57    39    00111001    9 
 58    3A    00111010    : 
 59    3B    00111011    ; 
 60    3C    00111100    < 
 61    3D    00111101    = 
 62    3E    00111110    > 
 63    3F    00111111    ? 
 64    40    01000000    @ 
 65    41    01000001    A 
 66    42    01000010    B 
 67    43    01000011    C 
 68    44    01000100    D 
 69    45    01000101    E 
 70    46    01000110    F 
 71    47    01000111    G 
 72    48    01001000    H 
 73    49    01001001    I 
 74    4A    01001010    J 
 75    4B    01001011    K 
 76    4C    01001100    L 
 77    4D    01001101    M 
 78    4E    01001110    N 
 79    4F    01001111    O 
 80    50    01010000    P 
 81    51    01010001    Q 
 82    52    01010010    R 
 83    53    01010011    S 
 84    54    01010100    T 
 85    55    01010101    U 
 86    56    01010110    V 
 87    57    01010111    W 
 88    58    01011000    X 
 89    59    01011001    Y 
 90    5A    01011010    Z 
 91    5B    01011011    [ 
 92    5C    01011100    \ 
 93    5D    01011101    ] 
 94    5E    01011110    ^ 
 95    5F    01011111    _ 
 96    60    01100000    ` 
 97    61    01100001    a 
 98    62    01100010    b 
 99    63    01100011    c 
100    64    01100100    d
101    65    01100101    e
102    66    01100110    f
103    67    01100111    g
104    68    01101000    h
105    69    01101001    i
106    6A    01101010    j
107    6B    01101011    k
108    6C    01101100    l
109    6D    01101101    m
110    6E    01101110    n
111    6F    01101111    o
112    70    01110000    p
113    71    01110001    q
114    72    01110010    r
115    73    01110011    s
116    74    01110100    t
117    75    01110101    u
118    76    01110110    v
119    77    01110111    w
120    78    01111000    x
121    79    01111001    y
122    7A    01111010    z
123    7B    01111011    {
124    7C    01111100    |
125    7D    01111101    }
126    7E    01111110    ~
127    7F    01111111    DEL
```

E esta:

```
Caracteres de controle
=======================================
Dec    Hex   Bin         Caractere
------ ----- ----------- --------------
 10    0A    00001010    avanço de linha
 13    0D    00001101    retorno de carro
 26    1A    00011010    SUB
 (tem outros, que nao vem ao caso agora)
```

Basta você filtrar a *string* de forma a eliminar acentos e caracteres especiais, de forma a não ter nenhum fora da tabela acima. Como fazer, só depende do jeito que está gerando cada linha.

Para inserir os caracteres `0x0D`, `0x0A` em PHP basta isso:

```
$quebra = chr( 0x0D ) . chr( 0x0A );

$final = chr( 0x1A );
```

PS: como já mencionado, pode usar "\r\n", mas dá exatamente no mesmo, veja no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/xKS0XD)**.

Aí você vai fazendo linha a linha:

```
$arquivo .= $linha . $quebra;
```

e no final

```
$arquivo .= $final;
```

Exemplo tirado de remessa real de banco, mas com o seu 0x1A acrescentado (no original não precisava disso, e separei as variáveis para ilustrar):

```
$quebra = chr( 0x0D ) . chr( 0x0A );
$final = chr( 0x1A );
$cRemessa := ''
... pulei a maior parte das linhas, mas só muda o conteudo ...
$cRemessa .= '1040001300021R 01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000204042018000000000000200                                                                                                                                                       ' + $quebra;
$cRemessa .= '10400015         000023000007000000000009002100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000                                                                                                                                                    ' + $quebra;
$cRemessa .= '10499999         000001000025                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ' + $quebra;
$cRemessa .= $final;
```

Lembre-se de dar scroll até o final à direita, pois a *string* tem muitos espaços em branco.

Comment: estou usando a constante PHP_EOL, ela por si só não coloca os caracteres chr( 0x0A ) + chr( 0x0D )? e a fclose() o chr( 0x1A ) estava lendo a documentação do php e ela da entender isso. Você sabe me dizer se procede isso ou não? Tem alguma forma de visualizar isso no arquivo para debugar? Mas de qualquer forma vou testar desta forma que você disse, pois ao transmitir ao banco o programa está acusando que tem um caractere a mais na linha e por isso criei o tópico, pois acabei por pensar que seria relacionado a codificação do arquivo

Comment: PHP_EOL depende do sistema. Não deve ser usado para esse etipo de aplicação, que tem especificação. FClose só fecha o arquivo, não teria sentido ele acrescentar caracteres arbitrários. O conteúdo de um arquivo é 100% responsabilidade do programador, você é quem decide o que vai nele.

Comment: Aliás, eu acho muito estranho uma remessa usar o 0x1A, vários bancos que eu faço remessa usam simplesmente uma quebra de linha normal no final da última linha (e é interessante que em muitos deles a documentação não era 100% correta)

Comment: Eu coloquei a quebra do jeito que você disse e não está fazendo a quebra de linha, porque será?

Comment: Tem que ver como é que você está testando pra ver a quebra. Espero que você esteja verificando o arquivo de verdade, e não olhando no browser.

Comment: Editei com um exemplo testado e funcional.

Comment: O problema é que para concatenar seria chr( 0x0A ).chr( 0x0D ) no php e eu não me atentei para isso. Bom agora está funcionando mas o banco continuar falando que tem um caracteres especiais, será que os espaços em branco que precisam por teria que ser com a função chr() ? eu estava usando a str_pad

Comment: Tanto faz como você cria a string, desde que cada campo tenha o tamanho certo (totalizando os 240 ou 400 caracteres, dependendo do padrão)

Comment: muito obrigado por tentar ajudar, mas usar a quebra de linha assim: chr( 0x0A ) + chr( 0x0D ) não deu certo. Ele cria espaço entre uma linha e outra e quando coloquei como o amigo Giavanni disse "\r\n" funcionou de primeira, eu não consegui entender mas  importante é que funcionou.

Comment: Editei a resposta com um demo, só pra vc ter como testar melhor: https://ideone.com/xKS0XD